# How to setup mongodb to came up with this URL

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

Hello it is my first in mongo db and allow me to ask this question.
I have this url to access but I alway got '**Invalid token**' following the set up provided in mongodb site.

url:

```
mongodb://usernameStr:passwordStr@localhost:27017/db?authSource=admin
```

can you please help me how to set up to came up with that url by accessing it successfully?

Comment: Can you share the complete snippet of JS where you attempt to establish the connection, and not just the URI?

Answer (score 0):

if you don't have mongoose then install via [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose). 
In your server.js file use the following code.

```
var url = your_url;

var options = {
  socketTimeoutMS: 30000,
  keepAlive: true,
  reconnectTries: Number.MAX_VALUE, // Never stop trying to reconnect
  reconnectInterval: 500, // Reconnect every 500ms
}

mongoose.connect(url, options).then(
 () => {
     dbStatus = true;
     console.log("DB connected!")
 },
  (error) => {
    dbStatus = false;
    console.log(error)
  }
);
```

Comment: Thank you @Leo, btw, do you know if this is still mongodb related. After connecting the db, the request header doesn't contain authorization property.